# Using select statement in rails queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have three tables,

products has 3 columns, let them be
product_id,retailer_id,id

product_urls has 2 columns, 
url_id,id

urls has 2 columns,
url_id, absolute_url

All the associations has been done in models.

Products & product_urls are joined on id = id (Products "has many" relationship with product_urls)

product_urls & urls are joined on Url_id = id (product_urls "belongs to" relationship with urls)

products & urls have "has many relationship"

I am trying to write a query, which selects A,B,C column from Table1 and X from Table3.

My query is:

- Product.joins(:urls).select(:product_id,:retailer_id,:absolute_url).where(:id=>100, :urls => {:url_id=>100})

I am able to execute the query without any error, but I am not able to get data for X. when I check for sql query it is

- select products.product_id, products.retailer_id, products.absolute_url ........ is executed.

Please help me how to fetch value from urls??

Comment: Try `Table1.joins(:table3).select("A,B,C,table3.X").where(:D=>100, :table3 => {:Y=>100})`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But, when I am using that it is erroring out as column is ambiguous

Comment: How you are using? Also Please post the real names of the tables and columns so that it would be easy to answer.

Comment: I modified the column names, Please have a look at this

Comment: Can you modify the table names as well?

Comment: yeah done.Check it now

Comment: Try this `Product.joins(:urls).select("products.product_id,products.retailer_id,urls.absolute_url").where(:id=>100, :urls => {:url_id=>100})`

Comment: It is executing without an error, but still unable to fetch data from absolute url

Comment: sorry previously mistake.. updated to this
`ProductUrl.includes(:product, :url).where(products: {id: 100}, urls: {url_id: 100}).map!{|pl| [pl.product.product_id, pl.product.retailer_id, pl.url.absolute_url]}`

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions. @pavan, it worked.

Comment: I need small Info, Is there any place other than official rails guide to get a clear ideas in this topic.?

Comment: As you said it is working. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
Product.joins(:urls).select("products.product_id,products.retailer_id,urls.abso‌​lute_url").where(:id=>100, :urls => {:url_id=>100})
```